# Картинка в бэкрануд, или просто картинкой?

Tags: html

Есть ли такое как лучше, например иконки класть в бэкраунд или картинками делать

Comment: от задачи зависит - если иконки надо анимировать и они в svg то inline если картинка статичная то просто тегом img или фоном

Comment: inline ?  inline block?

Comment: я про svg писал - nline- означает что код svg надо вставлять в html